# How to show the menus for a window in the window's title bar in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: kubuntu, qt5, menu-bar, plasma-5, kde5

I installed both the 'appmenu-qt' and 'appmenu-qt5' packages on a fresh install of Kubuntu 15.04. Then I looked in 'System Settings > Application Style', but found no options to enable the appmenu.

How does one enable the appmenu within the KDE Plasma 5.2.2 desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://launchpad.net/appmenu-qt5 
Maybe you need this: "To enable the support, set **QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5** in your environment."

You can do this be editing the file `~/.profile` and adding the line `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` at the tail end of the file, as in the following example:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```